# Calculating Lie bracket

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2)$. For which $a_1$ and $a_2$ does this hold $[a_1(x,y) \frac{\partial}{\partial x}+a_2(x,y) \frac{\partial}{\partial y}, f \frac{\partial}{\partial x}]$=0.

The problem for me is what to doe with the f in the lie Bracket. I found online that $$[X, fY ] = X(f)Y + f[X, Y ].$$
Here $X(f) := f_{*}(X)$. But I don't really how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

For all $g\in C^\infty(\Bbb R^2)$,$$\begin{align}0&=[a_1\partial_x+a_2\partial_y,\,f\partial_x]g\\&=a_1(fg_x)_x+a_2(fg_x)_y-f(a_1g_x+a_2g_y)_x\\&=a_1f_xg_x+a_1fg_{xx}+a_2f_yg_x+a_2fg_{xy}-fa_{1x}g_x-fa_1g_{xx}-fa_{2x}g_y-fa_2g_{yx}\\&=(a_1f_x+a_2f_y-fa_{1x})g_x-fa_{2x}g_y,\end{align}$$so $a_1f_x+a_2f_y=a_{1x}f$ and $a_{2x}f=0$. If this works for all $f\in C^\infty(\Bbb R^2)$, $a_1=a_2=0$. I'll leave you to consider which $a_1,\,a_2$ work for a specific $f$.

Answer (score 1):

If $X = X^i \partial_i$ and $Y = Y^j\partial_j$ in Einstein summation convention, then
\begin{align}
[X,Y] = (X^j\partial_jY^i - Y^j\partial_jX^i)\partial_i
\end{align}
Here, $X^1 = a_1$, $X^2=a_2$, $Y^1 = f$ and $Y^2=0$. Thus
\begin{align}
[X,Y] = (a_1\partial_xf + a_2\partial_yf - f\partial_x a_1)\partial_x + (-f\partial_xa_2)\partial_y
\end{align}
and this vector field is identically $0$ if and only if its components are zero, that is
\begin{align}
 a_1\partial_xf + a_2\partial_yf &= f\partial_xa_1& f\partial_ya_2&=0
\end{align}